# How to add a String into a BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to add this string for example: `"{% some_tag dog cat %}"` after some HTML element with BeautifulSoap.

I've used something like: `elem.insert_after(soup.new_string("{% some_tag dog cat %}"))` but this also added `</link></meta>` tags to the object.

How this can be done properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Python "html.parser" with BeautifulSoup that doesn't try to produce a valid document:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<h1>header</h1>', 'html.parser')
>>> soup
<h1>header</h1>
>>> str = NavigableString("{% some_tag dog cat %}")
>>> soup.append(str)
>>> soup
<h1>header</h1>{% some_tag dog cat %}
```

see also https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers